# How can we remove on server from Directory in OpenLdap?

Tags: security, directory, openldap

We installed a OpenLDAP 2.4.31 solution on debian; and several machines in the site are using it. Though the local authentication is not disabled on the machines. 
One of the machines has some problems; and its developers asked us to disable central authentication for it. Due to policy, we are not able to change anything on the machine itself; and only can configure our LDAP server. How can we disable one specific machine to use our LDAP server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the address of the machines from the LDAP servers; but make sure the machine doesn't get locked out!